# Have a populated spinner, want to test a string to see if it exists in spinner

Tags: android, spinner

Like the question says, I have a bunch of fully populated spinners. In a background thread I am taking data from somewhere, and when I get the data I want to display it.

If the spinner's contents contain the same string, I want to set the Spinner to the string I have, or N/A otherwise. ( N/A is at the top of every populated spinner )

EDIT :

Trying to clarify a bit more....

The spinner is initially filled with a bunch of values, and the default value is shown on the spinner.

Let's say the list is `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`.  The spinner would display nothing but the down arrow on it.

My application will read in data at some point. I want to search the spinner list, see if the data I have read in is in the list. Then, change the spinner from displaying nothing, to having the string I am looking for on it.

I literally can't think of how else to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            if(list.contains(ur_string))
            {
            int flag=1,i=0;
    while(flag==1)
    {
    String x=sp.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    if(x.equals(your_string))
    {
        spinner.setSelection(i);
        flag=0;
    }
    i++;
    }
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: can you explain your question little more?

Comment: if the string received is present in the string, what it have to do?

Comment: I want to change what is selected in the Spinner, programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Save your data in `List<String>` and using [list.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) you can check have string or not

```
public boolean containString(String chkString){

     if(list.contains(chkString)){
         return true;
     }
 return false; 
    }
```

Comment: I was wrong this isn't exactly the full answer to what I'm looking for. Once I find out if the list contains the string, I want to make THAT string be the spinner index displayed.

Comment: you can ask one question not more

Comment: What? You did not answer my original question.